# access web services with php

Tags: php, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to access `webservice` using `php`. I'm calling a method from the services then i get an error .

My code is below,help me sort this..

```
$message = $_REQUEST['message'];
$recipient ="250788353869";//$_REQUEST['recipient'];
$phone=(int)$recipient;
$account="";
$pin="";        
ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", "0"); // Set to zero to avoid caching WSDL
$soapClient = new SoapClient('http://gateway.esicia.com?wsdl');     
$result = $soapClient->ksend(array('account'=>$account,'pin'=>$pin,'sender'=>$sender_phone,'message'=>$message,'phone'=>$phone));    
print_r($result);
```

and error I get on the reply is:

> Notice: Array to string conversion in /opt/lampp/htdocs/Admin/sms/smspost.php on line 25
>       Array ( [reply] => Error Invalid phone - has to be numeric [balance] => [status] => 0 )

Comment: Can you show the line no 25 of smspost.php

Comment: here is the line the error is being displayed on: $result = $soapClient->ksend(array('account'=>$account,'pin'=>$pin,'sender'=>$sender_phone,'message'=>$message,'phone'=>$recipient)); @AmanRawat

Comment: this error comes when you try to use an array in place of string like for concatenation. So check all the variable you passed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The message you are seeing looks to be coming from the web services side, not yours. Chances are that the PHP Notice that's being thrown is invalidating the `XML` response. Your best bet is to get in contact with the company and report it as a bug.